# How to run the Bitcoin Core functional tests

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, functional-test

How do you run the functional tests from the Bitcoin Core Github repository?

Answer (score 1):

Clone a local copy of the repo and then from the project root:

```bash
test/functional/test_runner.py
```

(no `python3` or `./` required)

Minimum required python version is listed here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/.python-version

Documentation for running the functional tests is here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/test/README.md#functional-tests

Comment: Maybe point out they need to compile the project first?

Comment: I'm running bitcoin core. When I input that command into terminal I get 'Command not found'.